# how to get timezone offset for given day?

Tags: python, pytz

i want to convert given time from HK timezone to Australia timezone but for any historical day (not just today).  In Australia DST is applied on 2nd April this year. when i do following computation on dates after and before DST is applied, there should bea  difference of 1 hour. But I don't see any difference in the DST offsets on these 2 cases.

```
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime as dt

>>> autz=pytz.timezone("Australia/Sydney")
>>> hktz=pytz.timezone("Asia/Hong_Kong")

>>> x1=dt.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0,tzinfo=autz)
>>> x2=dt.datetime(2012,5,5,0,0,0,tzinfo=autz)

>>> hk1=x1.astimezone(hktz)
>>> hk2=x2.astimezone(hktz)

>>> x1
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Australia/Sydney' EST+10:00:00 STD>)
>>> hk1
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 31, 22, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Hong_Kong' HKT+8:00:00 STD>)
>>> x2
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Australia/Sydney' EST+10:00:00 STD>)
>>> hk2
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 4, 22, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Hong_Kong' HKT+8:00:00 STD>)
>>> autz=pytz.timezone("Australia/Sydney")
```

If you compare x1 with hk1 and x2 with hk2, in both cases, the difference between the times is 2 hours. But right now, as per DST, the difference between AU and HK is 3 hours and after 2nd April, the difference will be 2 hours.

Am I missing something? What is the correct way to get the correct time offsets during DST is on and when DST is off.

Regards,
Alok

Comment: worked fine when i used autz.localize() function. wonder why it doesn't work in above case. i guess limitations of the library.

Comment: You are right, you should not use `tzinfo=` with pytz, here a quote from its documentation: `Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors *does not work* with pytz for many timezones`. *localize()* is the way to go.